# Using node core http and viewing response. Where is the response json?

Tags: node.js, http, buffer

I am getting a 201 statusCode by running this code in Node. I am unsure how to view the response body that I am seeing in Postman. The response object is so big and overwhelming and after many searches, I just do not know what is going on. How can I view the response body json? Look at Postman image below, that response is what I am talking about. res.body, res.json() does not exist.

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers,
  hostname: uploadHostName,
  path: `/${uploadPath}`,
};

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  res.on('data', data => console.error({data}));

  res.on('error', error => console.error({error}));

  res.on('end', () => {
    const { statusCode, statusMessage } = res;
    console.log({ statusCode, statusMessage });
  });
});

const imageStream = fs.createReadStream(imageFile);

imageStream.pipe(req);

imageStream.on('end', () => {
  console.log("READ_STREAM_END")
  req.end();
});
```

[image: Postman response body]

Answer (score 0):

```
const req = https.request(options, res => {
  let chunks = [];

  res.on('data', data => chunks.push(data));

  res.on('error', error => console.error({error}));

  res.on('end', () => {
    const { statusCode, statusMessage, body } = res;
    // console.log(Object.keys(res.client))
    console.log({ statusCode, statusMessage, body });
    console.log(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString());
  });
});
```

I did not realize what the chunks were. For some reason, I was thinking this data was the uploaded file. I was also confused about that - why would it send the upload data to the res? Then It dawned on me after taking a short break. The res.on('data') is probably the strigified json I need!